# How to setup a link that will send emails with subject line, to field, and body and put it on social media

Tags: html, email

I was wondering if it was possible to create a mailto like link which people can click and it will open their default mailing app with the inputed subject line, to field and email body.

I want to use this to put in my Instagram bio so that people can click on that link and have an email ready to send.

I'm a complete noob so initially I tried copy pasting a whole mailto line into the Instagram bio because copy pasting it into a browser seemed to work, but Instagram doesn't allow that and changes the link to just be Gmail.com.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If Instagram doesn't allow it, then you can't do it. Unless you link to another page that does it, like @leo848 mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There is a website called https://mailxto.com that you help you achieve exactly what you are looking for.

It lets you a mailto: code into a clickable link by shorting it. you should checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very complex, but it will definitely work.

First, sign up to [GitHub](https://github.com) if you haven't already. Create a new repository and name it whatever you want. Then add a new file called `index.html` and paste this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=mailto:me@example.com?subject=Contact%20me">
        <title>Redirecting to email...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        If you don't get redirected in 12 seconds automatically, you should
        <a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=Contact%20me">click this link</a
        >.
    </body>
</html>
```

Now set up GitHub pages. Click settings and go to github pages. Then select from master branch. Your domain should be [username].github.io/[repo name].
Set this domain in your Instagram bio or shorten it with [Bitly](https://bit.ly) first.

Comment: I know the basics of using the mailto tag for when I'm making webpages. But my issue was with turning it into a link that I could pass around in social media where someone would click it and it would run like the mailto tag.

Comment: I changed the solution so it will definitely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mailto` protocol which allows opening a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message.

```
mailto:sAddress[sHeaders]
```

where

`sAddress`  - One or more valid e-mail addresses separated by a semicolon. You must use Internet-safe characters, such as "%20" for the space character.

`sHeaders` - One or more name-value pairs. The first pair should be prefixed by a "?" and any additional pairs should be prefixed by a "&". The name can be one of the following strings.

- subject -  Text to appear in the subject line of the message.
- body  - Text to appear in the body of the message.
- CC - Addresses to be included in the "cc" (carbon copy) section of the message.
- BCC - Addresses to be included in the "bcc" (blind carbon copy) section of the message.

Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later. You must percent-encode all URL-reserved characters within a mailto: address. For example, the number sign (#) is used as a fragment identifier in URLs. When processing an address such as some#one@example.com, Internet Explorer copies only the portion up to the number sign into the mail client; the fragment portion including the number sign is ignored. This behavior is by design.

For more information on the `mailto` protocol, see [RFC2368: The mailto URL scheme](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=203480).

Comment: I know the basics of using the mailto tag for when I'm making webpages. But my issue was with turning it into a link that I could pass around in social media where someone would click it and it would run like the mailto tag

Comment: Did you try to wrap the mailto string with `<a>` tag?